# How to decode base64 to single bytes?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, base64, ascii

In the following code:

```
import base64
base64.decodebytes('DBCCOAABAMA='.encode('ascii'))
```

the result is

```
b'\x0c\x10\x828\x00\x01\x00\xc0'
```

The third byte is `\x828` which does not fit into a single byte and lead into a problem for my script. I do not want to decode it as anything else than `ASCII`.

Is there anything wrong with the initial base64 encoder?
Why does this problem happen and how can I fix it?

---

Update:

The problem I face is the code

```
base64.decodebytes('DBCCOAABAMA='.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
```

leads to an error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some bytes, if they fall in the printable character range, don't get printed as hex escapes.  This little bit of code shows you what's really happening:

```
>>> for b in base64.decodebytes('DBCCOAABAMA='.encode('ascii')):
    print(hex(b), chr(b))

0xc 
0x10 
0x82 ‚
0x38 8
0x0 
0x1 
0x0 
0xc0 À
```

P.S.  I don't understand why `encode` didn't throw an error, some of those bytes are outside of the ASCII range.

Comment: The problem I face is the code `base64.decodebytes('DBCCOAABAMA='.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')` leads to an error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)`.

Comment: @mercury then you have to find out what the true encoding is, because it certainly isn't ASCII.

Comment: an ascii can be any value between 0x00 to 0xFF isn't it?

Comment: @mercury no, ASCII only officially goes to 0x7f.  There are lots of extensions that use the 0x80-0xff range, but they're called something else.

Comment: what decode should I choose for range 0x00 to 0xFF sharp? Is it `iso-8859-1`?

Comment: @mercury I can't answer that for you, but it would be a good place to start.  If you have some documentation for the source of your data I'd look there.